# KeyError while reading configuration from .ini file using configparser in cmd, but it's ok in PyCharm

Tags: python, ini, configparser, keyerror

I'm writing russian comments, so i use utf-8 config.ini:

```
; Файл конфигурации
; Название секции писать в квадратных скобках,
; например [Example]
; Параметры писать в виде param_name = value
[default]
; Имя выходного html файла
out_file = cities.html
; Заголовок сгенерированной html страницы
file_title = cities
[filterparams]
; Параметры для фильтрации всех постов
; Значения по-умолчанию
; Минимальный индекс климата
climate_index = 60.0
; Минимальная температура(В градусах по Цельсию)
temp_min = 15
; Максимальная температура(В градусах по Цельсию)
temp_max = 24
; По уровню жизни город в ТОП-...
amount = 50
```

config_loader.py (Reading configuration + "configuration" function makes a dictionary from a section):

```
try:
assert os.path.exists('E:\pythoncodes\config.ini')
except:
print('Нет файла конфигурации config.ini')
exit(1)

try:
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini', encoding="utf-8")
except configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError:
print('Ошибка в названии секции в файле config.ini')
exit(1)
except configparser.ParsingError:
print("Ошибка в парсинге конфигурационного файла")
exit(1)

def configuration(section):
cfg = dict(config[section])
return cfg
```

This is usual function call:

```
cfg = configuration("filterparams")
```

In PyCharm it works well, but there is a KeyError, when I open it in cmd. This is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\pythoncodes\main.py", line 3, in <module>
from reading import read
File "E:\pythoncodes\reading.py", line 4, in <module>
from parsing import json_parsing
File "E:\pythoncodes\parsing.py", line 20, in <module>
cfg = configuration("filterparams")
File "E:\pythoncodes\config_loader.py", line 23, in configuration
cfg = dict(config[section])
File "E:\python\lib\configparser.py", line 959, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'filterparams'
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that you load a different config.ini? Can you try with the full path in `config.read(...)`?

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille Yeah, it helped me. Thank you